# How to rework Sql to Yii2 with Left Join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I have a db where I need to calculate the values of the two tables.

Table Forc:

- rft
- cos.

Table Prod:

- w
- efr
- result.

Formula:  `$x = (w * efr) / rft * (1 + (cos / 10)`.

So on raw SQL it will be something like this:

```
UPDATE Prod
   SET result = w*eft / 
      (SELECT Forc.rft * (1 + Forc.cos / 10)
         FROM Forc
        WHERE Forc.id=Prod.id)
```

But I don't know how it build with Left join, especially on Yii2. So that request must change the value "result", when the user enters a value in a cells as defined in formula.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why you can't use [createCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#createCommand()-detail) + `bindValue` for raw sql? `$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
$command = $connection->createCommand("your query here"); $command->execute();`

Comment: Yes, this works. In question, I gave an example of a simple formula. For task it's ~20 interrelated formulas with different tables. But I thought it more correct to use through `Join`. For example, how to use `Join` I know:  `$x = (newQuery())->select()->from()->leftJoin()->where()->groupBy()`. But with `Update` when I tried to use `Join` I got an error.